# Converting Python buffer to NumPy array - ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size

Tags: python, mysql, numpy

I'm attempting to read a BLOB object from a MySQL database in Python. The BLOB object is a NumPy array.

To convert the array to a buffer type for insertion into the database I use the following function:

`numpy.getbuffer(arr)`

Upon reading back I am able to recreate the buffer object via:

`bytes(memoryview(arr))`

*Everything is working correctly at this point.* My issue arises when using the below function on the buffer object in an attempt to convert it back to a NumPy array:

`numpy.frombuffer(arr, dtype=numpy.float64)`

The error is as follows:

`ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size`

Please note that the dtype is set correctly, my Python version is 2.7.13 and NumPy is 1.13.3.

EDIT: So upon doing some further digging, here is some extra information and a peculiarity on which I have stumbled:

The length of the `numpy.getbuffer(arr)` object is 7392. If I print the length of the returned value as is from the MySQL DB (returned using `cursor.fetchall() or fetchone()` for example, the length is 7668.

So I printed the first 30 characters of each object, and while they are clearly the same thing, the object returned from the DB has a number of additional characters:

Before DB:
`?=G????B?i?j??w??LG???ࢩ?a`

After DB:
`'?=G????B?i?\0j??w??LG???ࢩ?`

I assume that the issue stems from the way the data is stored in the DB. My reasoning is that the following code produces no errors:

`numpy.frombuffer(numpy.getbuffer(arr), dtype=numpy.float64)`

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: So can you check the size of this buffer?  `len(arr)` or length of the `bytes` version?

Comment: Interesting... length of the buffer object on creation (prior to writing to the DB) is 7392. Length of the bytes(memoryview(bufferobject)) is only 23...

Comment: are you able to convert buffer back to numpy without passing the dtype: numpy.frombuffer(arr)?  Also try converting numpy to buffer with specific dtype numpy.getbuffer(arr, dtype=numpy.float64) and reverting it with numpy.frombuffer(arr, dtype=numpy.float64)

Comment: You can't specify `dtype` with the `frombuffer` func and and using `getbuffer` without the `dtype` also gives the same error. I have noticed something interesting though, please see the edit.